# YiiBooster TbButtonGroup how to change the color of the selected button

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have the following Yii Booster TbButtonGroup, inside a rendered modal:

```
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButtonGroup',array(
'buttons' => array(
    array('label' => 'Low Danger',  
          'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'id' => 'lowDangerButton', 
                'onClick'=>'function()
                    {
                        $("#symptomFlagTextField").val("1");
                        $("#lowDangerButton").addClass("selectedFlag");
                    }')),
    array('label' => 'Mild Danger', 'htmlOptions'=>array('id' => 'mildDangerButton', 'onClick'=>'$("#symptomFlagTextField").val("2");')),
    array('label' => 'High Danger', 'htmlOptions'=>array('id' => 'highDangerButton', 'onClick'=>'$("#symptomFlagTextField").val("3");'))
    ),
)
);
```

What I want to do is that when the user presses a button, that's button's color will change to something different for each button (first button should turn green, second yellow and 3rd red).

I tried doing it by adding a class to the button (you can see an example of this with the first button), but when I run it it won't add the class to the button. But the first command in the function ($("#symptomFlagTextField").val("1"); ) works perfectly.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or any other options to get the same effect.

Thank you for your time

**FIXED**

Made a seperate js function
    function dothis()
    {
        $("#symptomFlagTextField").val("1");
        $("#lowDangerButton").addClass("selectedFlag");
    }

And just set "onClick"=>"dothis()"

Comment: $("#lowDangerButton"), there's missing '#'

Comment: that was a typo I guess. It's not that, I put it back and still not working :(

Comment: I tried adding a class to a random div inside the modal the buttonGroup is in, and it also didn't work for that. I was wondering if something is wrong with jQuery, but the .val() function is working so that's not it.

Comment: Turns out that the class wasn't being added because the "onClick" can only run a single js command :/. I guess it is something with how bootstrap/booster works. Anyway, I managed to fix it by just writing a separate js function in a script file and calling that onClick.